# Understanding the "this" keyword in Typescript with event binding

Tags: typescript

I am currently working on a small Typescript project and I face some difficulties trying to bind event to `HTMLElement`. I've looked at various questions and answers on SO but none of me really helped me...

Here is a minimal working example:

```
class X {
    constructor(a: HTMLElement) {
        var _this0 = this; // class X, OK
        a.addEventListener('click', (ev: MouseEvent) => {
            var _this1 = this; // class X, why?
        });
        a.addEventListener('click', function (ev: MouseEvent) {
            var _this2 = this; // any... I assume HTMLElement (a)?
        });
    }
};
```

I do not understand why `_this1` is of type `X` and not of type `HTMLElement` (or `any`)? It seems to work with the standard javascript `function` but not with the `Typescript` lambda syntax.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?hd=1&v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have annotated your code to explain `this`.

```
class X {
    constructor(a: HTMLElement) {
        var _this0 = this; // class X, OK
        a.addEventListener('click', (ev: MouseEvent) => {

            // Because you have used an arrow function
            // () => { }
            // Use of "this" within this function will
            // mean the original lexical scope, "class X"

            var _this1 = this; // class X, why ?
        });
        a.addEventListener('click', function (ev: MouseEvent) {

            // Because you have used a function
            // function () { }
            // The function will be scoped within the context it
            // it calls, for an event, it will be the event target

            var _this2 = this; // any... I assume HTMLElement (a) ?
        });
    }
};
```

Essentially, use of arrow functions preserve the lexical scope (which means the scope inside the function remains the same, which isn't the usual situation in JavaScript).

So when you write:

```
    a.addEventListener('click', (ev: MouseEvent) => {
        var x = this;
    });
```

It is compiled to:

```
    var _this = this;
    a.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        var x = _this;
    });
```

By the TypeScript compiler.

If you need both the original `this` and the contextual `this`, you would use:

```
    var _self = this;
    a.addEventListener('click', function (ev: MouseEvent) {
        var x = this; // The event target
        var y = _self; // class X
    });
```